# JADE - Parallel behaviours amongst 2 agents does not work

Tags: java, agents-jade

I was trying to implement  parallelism amongst 2 agents, by following the procedure provided [here](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Evaucher/Agents/Jade/primer3.html#3.7).
The output I got (as shown below) is completely different to what is to be expected.
The program prints the name of the agent and the current system time during the action being performed. I tried performing parallelism amongst 2 agents where each agent is supposed to print their own name and current time, but only the latter of the 2 agents is performing its action.

> javac test.java
> java jade.Boot -agents aaa:test ccc:test
> ....
> Agent container Main-Container@192.168.122.1 is ready.
>
> 100: ccc
> 200: ccc
> 300: ccc
> 400: ccc
> 500: ccc

This was the code that I implemented

```
import jade.core.Agent;
import jade.core.behaviours.*;

public class test extends Agent{

protected void setup(){
addBehaviour(new Looper(this,100));
}

}

class Looper extends SimpleBehaviour
{
    static String offset = "";
    static long   t0     = System.currentTimeMillis();

    String tab = "" ;
    int    n   = 1;
    long   dt;

    public Looper( Agent a, long dt) {
            super(a);
            this.dt = dt;
            offset += "    " ;
            tab = new String(offset) ;
    }

    public void action()
    {
            System.out.println( tab +
               (System.currentTimeMillis()-t0)/10*10 + ": " +
                    myAgent.getLocalName() );
            block( dt );
            n++;
    }

    public  boolean done() {  return n>6;  }

}
```

Expected output:

> java jade.Boot aa:Agent1 zzzzz:Agent1
>
> 0: zzzzz
> 0: aa
> 10: zzzzz
> 10: aa
> 300: zzzzz
> 310: aa
> 510: zzzzz
> 510: aa
> 610: zzzzz
> 610: aa
> 910: zzzzz
> 920: aa
> 1020: zzzzz
> 1020: aa
> 1220: zzzzz
> 1220: aa
> 1520: zzzzz
> 1520: aa
> 1520: zzzzz
> 1530: aa
> 2030: zzzzz
> 2030: aa
> 2530: zzzzz
> 2530: aa

Comment: When you use the `-gui` option, do you see the two agents in the container? What other useful informations do you see in the GUI when you try to start your agents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about "-agents" option which is a semicolon separated list of agent's specifiers. You can replace by this:

```
java -cp jade.Boot -agents "aaa:test;ccc:test"
```

or specifying classpath:

```
java -cp /home/myusername/jadelibpath/libjade-4.3.jar:. jade.Boot -agents "aaa:test;ccc:test"
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thank you.